# postorder traversal a tree with javascript or jquery to create html codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to create Html Codes like this

```
<ul>
    <li>子菜单1
        <ul>
            <li>子菜单1.1</li>
            <li>子菜单1.2
                <ul>
                    <li>子菜单1.2.1</li>
                    <li>子菜单1.2.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>子菜单2
        <ul>
            <li>子菜单2.1</li>
            <li>子菜单2.2
                <ul>
                    <li>子菜单2.2.1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>子菜单3</li>
</ul>
```

Now I have been transfer some json Data To HTML page like this

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: '子菜单1',
    parentid:
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: '子菜单2',
    parentid:
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: '子菜单3',
    parentid:
}, {
    id: 4,
    name: '子菜单1.1',
    parentid: 1
}, {
    id, 5,
    name: '子菜单1.2',
    parentid: 1
}, {
    id: 6,
    name: '子菜单1.2.1',
    parentid: 5
}, {
    id: 7,
    name: '子菜单1.2.2',
    parentid: 5
}, {
    id, 8,
    name: '子菜单2.1',
    parentid: 2
}, {
    id: 9,
    name: '子菜单2.2',
    parentid: 2
}, {
    id: 10,
    name: '子菜单2.2.1',
    parentid: 9
}, {
    id: 11,
    name: '子菜单3',
    parentid:
}]
```

So I want to write some javascript or jquery code to create the html as I want

maybe there are some ways to touch the goal

maybe postorder traversal  the tree 
when view the root node,then add the childnode lists  like'`<ul><li></li>....</ul>`' to rootNode so they can be create to  `<li><ul>...</ul></li>`

sorry my English is very poor

can you get it?

can you help me?

Comment: what you have tried so far???

Comment: I can generate the html code with  back end code(C#),but I think this way is not so good,so I want to make this with javascript or jquery code.But front-end is hard to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. We can print the tree by performing a depth-first traversal. For each node, we print the opening tag and the `name` value, then descend into each of the children. When the recursion is done, we print the closing tag.

The code belows builds the tree with the help of an index called `id_to_node`, which maps the `id` key values to previously built nodes. This assumes that the input array contains the objects ordered in such a way that each `parentid` refers to an earlier element in the array. If this is not true, you'll have to traverse the input twice: first to build the index, and the second time to build the tree.

```js
var data = [ { id: 1, name: '子菜单1' },
             { id: 2, name: '子菜单2' },
             { id: 3, name: '子菜单3' },
             { id: 4, name: '子菜单1.1', parentid: 1 },
             { id: 5, name: '子菜单1.2', parentid: 1 },
             { id: 6, name: '子菜单1.2.1', parentid: 5 },
             { id: 7, name: '子菜单1.2.2', parentid: 5 },
             { id: 8, name: '子菜单2.1', parentid: 2 },
             { id: 9, name: '子菜单2.2', parentid: 2 },
             { id: 10, name: '子菜单2.2.1', parentid: 9 } ];

var id_to_node = {},           // Map id values to nodes.
    tree = { children: [] };   // The root of the tree.

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var object = data[i],        // Iterate over the objects.
      node = { id: object.id, name: object.name, children: [] };
  id_to_node[object.id] = node;
  if (object.parentid === null || object.parentid === undefined) {
    var parent = tree;         // Figure out the object's parent.
  } else {
    var parent = id_to_node[object.parentid];
  }
  parent.children.push(node);  // Add the node to the parent.
}


// Makes whitespace for each level of the tree.
function indent(depth) {
  var spaces = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
    spaces.push('    ');
  }
  return spaces.join('');
}

// Recursively prints the tree.
function print(node, depth) {
  document.write(indent(depth)+'&lt;ul&gt;\n');
  for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; ++i) {
    var child = node.children[i];
    document.write(indent(depth+1)+'&lt;li&gt;'+child.name);
    if (child.children.length > 0) {
      document.write('\n');
      print(child, depth+2);
      document.write(indent(depth+1));
    }
    document.write('&lt;li&gt;\n');
  }
  document.write(indent(depth)+'&lt;ul&gt;\n');
}

document.write('<pre>');
print(tree, 0);
document.write('</pre>');
```